# Supressing AZ cli errors when calling az network vnet peering show

Tags: powershell, azure-cli

I have got the code below which will check to see if a network peering exists and act accordingly, I recently changed the bicep pipeline to add `failOnStandardError: true` as I noticed that sometimes the bicep code would fail but the pipeline gives the impression it ran successfully.

`$peering = az network vnet peering show -g xxx  -n enter-wrong-peering--vnet-name vnet_name --query "name" --output tsv`

This returns the error.

`ERROR: (NotFound) Resource /subscriptions/xx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/xxx/virtualNetworkPeerings/xxx not found. Code: NotFound Message: Resource /subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xx/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/xxx/xxx not found.`

My question is, is there a way to silence this section of the code below ?

```
      $ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
      try {

            $peering = az network vnet peering show -g xxx  -n enter-wrong-peering--vnet-name vnet_name --query "name" --output tsv
          }
      catch {
          Write-Output "Peering does not exist"
      }
```

I have tried to place the code in a try/catch block and setting the Errorcontrol to `SilentlyContinue`

Comment: `$ErrorActionPreference = SilentlyContinue` should work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried redirecting the stderr output?

```
$peering = az network vnet peering show -g xxx  -n enter-wrong-peering--vnet-name vnet_name --query "name" --output tsv 2>error.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. As the script was running from a pipeline, i redirected to $null